# Vertical alignment instructions are reversed with tabular

Tags: tables, arrays

According to Overleaf documentation for [tables](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/tables), I have to use `m{}`, `p{}` or `b{}` to vertically align my text, but for some unknown reason, in a three-column test table, the instruction in the first column has an effect on the third column (here `m{}`), the second has an effect on the first, and the third has an effect on the second column.

Here is a minimal example from the overleaf documentation. I have the same effect on overleaf and on my local installation updated in October 2020.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|b{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Country List} \\
  \hline
  Country Name or Area Name& ISO ALPHA 2 Code &ISO ALPHA 3 \\
  \hline
  Afghanistan & AF &AFG \\
  Aland Islands & AX   & ALA \\
  Albania &AL & ALB \\
  Algeria    &DZ & DZA \\
  American Samoa & AS & ASM \\
  Andorra & AD & AND   \\
  Angola & AO & AGO \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Would you know why? This is the first time I have this problem in 9 years of using Latex. Is it a bug in the last `array` package version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say that the columns influence each other. The output is precisely what it should be. The `p`-column is basically a top-aligned `\parbox`, the `b`-column a bottom-aligned one, and the `m` column a center-aligned one. If I add the baselines in your `tabular`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\def\foo{\leavevmode\hbox to 0pt{\hss \vrule width 5cm height .4pt\hss}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|b{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Country List} \\
  \hline
  \foo Country Name or Area Name& ISO ALPHA 2 Code\foo & \foo ISO ALPHA 3 \\
  \hline
  Afghanistan & AF &AFG \\
  Aland Islands & AX   & ALA \\
  Albania &AL & ALB \\
  Algeria    &DZ & DZA \\
  American Samoa & AS & ASM \\
  Andorra & AD & AND   \\
  Angola & AO & AGO \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

you'll see that the bottom line of the second (`b`) column is correctly aligned with the top (and only) line of the third (`p`) column; the first column (`m`) is centered, so its top baseline is higher.

To make more clear what the alignment with respect to the baseline means, consider the following sequence of three `\parbox`es

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\baseline}{\rule{1cm}{.2pt}}
\newcommand*{\foo}[1]{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}\fbox{\parbox[#1]{1cm}{\raggedright Foo bar baz bar}}}}
\begin{document}
\baseline\foo{c}\baseline\foo{b}\baseline\foo{t}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hum ok I see, thank you. I understand for the first column, but for the others, when overleaf say "paragraph column with text vertically aligned at the top", what is the reference? It's aligned relative to what? If the reference is the baseline in middle, for the third column I expected the text to be under the line.

Comment: The reference is the *baseline*. For `p` column (top-aligned) it's not the top of the whole thing, but the baseline of the top line.

Comment: @JosephGarnier See edit; maybe it's clearer now.

Comment: ho ok, your edit helped me a lot. Thanks again.